# Backbone object memory questions

Tags: performance, backbone.js, backbone.js-collections, backbone-model

Have a backbone-driven app, and looking for some information on performance. At any point in time, the app is managing between 2,500 and 15,000 objects (specifically, models, spread across maybe 50 collections)

I'm trying to find details on what Backbone can handle (each object is generally quite small, with a small set of custom-methods available to it)

Any direction to look for this would be great.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is not question of what can Backbone handle but what is is the amount of available memory at a runtime. 15,000 objects is quite few to store in mem, you might have some rendering performance issues if you try to display each object as page element(s) though.

You can try standard memory profiling (https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/heap-profiling) or check this Backbone debugger (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/backbone-debugger/bhljhndlimiafopmmhjlgfpnnchjjbhd).

Comment: Thanks @Radek. Likely won't be displaying all the objects in DOM. Only a small fraction of them.

Comment: You're welcome.. Could you please accept the answer?